# The limit of $\frac{1}{x}$, as $x \to 0$ doesnt exist, or does it?

Tags: calculus

Obviously, if you approach $0$ from left you get $-\infty$, if you approach from right you get $+\infty$. Ergo, the limit doesnt exist.

But what if we work in the number system of where, to real numbers we adjoin a single unsigned infinity? In that case the limit from left and right is the same: infinity. So the limit does exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you change the number system in which you are working, you should expect that the values of limits should change as well.  With the typical real number system, the limit does not exist.  With your altered system of numbers, I really don't know (I'm out of my element there).

Comment: It's convention to say that it doesn't exist.

Comment: The limit would exist in [such a space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line)

Comment: But that sequence is not a Cauchy sequence; why do you expect that the limit exists in any case?

Comment: Yeah you're missing something. The limit! Show me the deltas and epsilons.

Comment: @awllower: I hope I am not saying something stupid, but its not a sequence: Cauchy, or otherwise. Its a function.

Comment: @DavidH: good Idea, I will try to do that and report.

Comment: I think you are asking for the limit of a sequence? How can a function have a limit? If you are trying to define the function $1/x$ entirely on $\mathbb R$, then of course you can define it as $\infty$ in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I dont see why a function coudlnt have a limit. Also the question of the limit when x goes to zero is a seperate one from how we might choose to define the function at 0 in some compactification, no?

Comment: OK. Maybe I am too ignorant. I would like to know how one defines the limit of a function. Thanks. :)

Comment: I am not the most qualified person but basically the closer x is to a certain value (in our case 0), the closer should f(x) get to a certain value and in fact no matter how small a tolerance you choose you should be able to find an x such f(x) is within that tolerance.

Comment: And we usally call such a function *continuous* at $x$?

Comment: That seems correct. I read that these two concepts are very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of. What you're describing is the [one-point compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $\mathbb{R}$. By 'joining the ends' at a single new point $\infty$ you obtain something that looks like a circle, on which the map $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ well-defined (and continuous) even at $0$.

The notion of 'limit' in this space makes slightly less sense, though, because there is no extension of the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ to a metric on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$: if there were then we'd need every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to have infinite distance from $\infty$. We can make sense of limits, but not using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

To be precise: open sets in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ are

- open sets in $\mathbb{R}$; and
- sets containing $\infty$ whose complements are closed, bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

We then say $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ if for every open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ with $L \in U$ there exists an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ containing $a$ such that, whenever $x \in V$ and $x \ne a$ then $f(x) \in U$.

According to *this* definition we have
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x} = \infty$$

...but don't make the mistake of thinking that this implies anything about the value of $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}$: it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Indeed, if the compactification is metrisable, then the sequence $\{1/x\}$ would be a Cauchy sequence, with $x$ approaching $0$. But that is not the case.

Comment: @awllower: Would you please explain to me what does metrisable mean?

Comment: @Adam: Metrisable means there is a metric on the space inducing its topology. Do you know what a metric is? If not, you may be in a bit over your head with this, but in any case just think 'distance function'. In a metric space, we can make sense of any two points having (finite) distance from each other. When you can define a metric on a space, you can define limits by generalising the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition. But when your space admits no metric, you need to define limits in another manner... see my edit for how they're defined here.

Comment: The usual definition of limit doesnt apply, since we have no concept of a distance, right? How come we cannot define a metric on this space?

Comment: @Adam: This space *is* metrisable (I mean, it's homeomorphic to a circle), but there is no extension of the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ to a new metric on this space because the new point $\infty$ is 'too far away'.

Comment: Is it because all the distances have to be finite for us to be able to define a distance-function?

Comment: @Adam: That's right. If you allow for infinite distances then limits just "don't work". If you're interested in this stuff I recommend learning topology at some point in the future. It's really fun :)

Comment: But we do have a concept of nearness, so that we can define open sets, is that correct?

Comment: @Adam: No, 'nearness' and 'distance' are pretty much the same thing. See my answer for the definition of open sets: the open sets are the same as usual if they don't contain $\infty$, and otherwise they're "really big open sets" that do contain $\infty$.

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of an open set containing infinity?

Comment: Sure: the whole set. Or, more generally, the whole set minus a closed interval, e.g. $(\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}) \setminus [-1,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the fact that the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to the circle, hence metrisable. And I forgot that the sequence is simply not Cauchy under the standard metric on $\mathbb R$, while it might still be Cauchy under other metrics. Sorry for that.